# Form validation issue in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to django. Here,I want to create login for my django app.When I am trying to create user account,It gives the following error

`FieldError at /signup/ Cannot resolve keyword 'mobile' into field 
Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, user_permissions, username, userregform`

While creating user account, I want to add username,email,mobile no,password and organisation name.If email or mobile no already exist, it should give the error message

And here is my code

**forms.py**

```
User=get_user_model()

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email=forms.EmailField(label='Email address')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',
                          widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    def clean(self,*args,**kwargs):
        email=self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password=self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        if email and password:
            user=authenticate(email=email,password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This email id is not registered")
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")
            return super(UserLoginForm,self).clean(*args,**kwargs)
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username= forms.CharField(label='Username')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address')
    mobile =forms.CharField(label='Mobile No')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password')
    org_name = forms.CharField(label='Organisation Name')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'mobile', 'password','org_name']
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        check_duplicate_email = User.objects.filter (email=email).exists()
        if check_duplicate_email:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
            "This email id is already registered"
            )
        return email
    def clean_mobile(self):
        mobile=self.cleaned_data.get('mobile')
        check_duplicate_mobile=User.objects.filter(mobile=mobile).exists()
        if check_duplicate_mobile:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
              "This mobile no is already registered"
            )
        return mobile
```

**models.py**

```
class UserRegForm(models.Model):
    email=models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True)
    mobile =models.CharField(max_length=10)
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
```

**views.py**

```
def login(request):
    title="Login"
    form=UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        email=form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user=authenticate(email=email,password=password)
        login(request,user)
    return render(request,"userRegistration/login.html",{"form":form,"title":title})
def signup(request):
    title="Signup"
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        print form.is_valid() #print False
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save(commit=False)
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user=set_password(password)
            user.save()
            new_user = authenticate(email=user.email, password=password)
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect("userRegistration/a.html")
    else:
        form=RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, "userRegistration/signup.html", {"form":form,"title":title})
```

**html**

```
    {% block title %}Registration{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
        <h1>Registration</h1>
        {% if form.errors %}
        <h1>Error</h1>
        {% endif %}

        <form method="post" action="{% url 'userRegistration:signup' %}"">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
        {% endif %}

{% endblock %}</html>
```

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback in your questions. It shows exactly where the error is occurring in your code.

Comment: `RegistrationForm` is for the `User` model, but `mobile` is in the `UserRegForm` model. Therefore you can't include `mobile` in `RegistrationForm.fields`.

Comment: Then How can I add the mobile field in user accounts?

Comment: One option would be to move the `mobile` field to your custom user model. If you want to have a separate profile model then [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html#sign-up-with-profile-model) should help.

Comment: As an aside, you still haven't included the full traceback in your question. It shows really useful information like the line numbers where the error occurred, and can help identify exactly where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RegistrationForm` use `User` model. I don't know where it is. (Maybe django default `User` model? ) But then you can't use fields from other model. (In this situation, `UserRegForm`).

If you add some fields while signup, you have to add it after signup done.

Just remove your `clean_mobile` from your form and add it in `signup` view. like below (It's just example. You have to customize for your own way

```
def signup(request):
    title="Signup"
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        print form.is_valid() #print False
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save(commit=False)
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user=set_password(password)
            user.save()
            # and save UserRegForm model here
            # and call clean_mobile here
            mobile = clean_mobile(form.cleaned_data.get('mobile')
            UserRegForm.create(
                email=user, 
                mobile=mobile
                ...
            )
            new_user = authenticate(email=user.email, password=password)
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect("userRegistration/a.html")
    else:
        form=RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, "userRegistration/signup.html", {"form":form,"title":title})
```